# Pros and cons of security images

Tags: authentication

Over the past year or so, I've noticed that all of the banking organizations I work with that have or had "security images" as part of their login process have removed or are planning to remove that feature. Such organizations include [Ally Bank](http://www.ally.com/learn/new-login/), [Bank of America](http://info.bankofamerica.com/new-sign-in/), and Amazon Store Card by [Synchrony Bank](https://www.onlinecreditcenter6.com/dualcardimages/plcc/amazon/en/images/marketingimage.gif). I thought the purpose of that feature was to make login more secure, so why are they removing the feature? Is there some newly-discovered theory or some such that has made companies feel that this is a feature that should be removed?

Comment: Actually, many institutions have removed site images due to pending litigation by patent trolls.

Answer (score 0):

One of your link refers to SiteKey (BOA): actually there is an interesting study on it conducted by Harvard University and which I recommend you to read [The Emperor’s New Security Indicators: An evaluation of website authentication and the effect of role playing on usability studies](http://commerce.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/The%20Emperors_New_Security_Indicators.pdf).

First, this technique was seen as a  [defense-in-depth](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Defense_in_depth) strategy intended to mainly help  foil  [phishing attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phishing). Nevertheless, studies as the one we mentioned, show this technique is a worthless measure as it is less effective than one might think.

Actually, the above empirical study, for example, proofs that  users have been attacked with two types of attacks: phishing attacks ***and*** [MITM](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack) attacks (SSL stripping).

The study above was performed on 3 groups of users:

- Groupe 1: usres perform banking tasks using their credentials on their own banking web site
- Groupe 2: users perform banking tasks every Sunday afternoon
- Groupe 3: similar to Group 2 but users were taught additional instructions to behave securely.

Researchers (who played the role of an attacker), offered login pages with security images where `https://` is substituted by `http://`: **all** (the three groups)  users typed their credentials.

When the attackers removed away the authentication images were removed and replaced them with warning messages such as *This service is being upgraded*, 99% of the users (including the ones who have taught security behaviors) typed their credentials.

Conclusion: as security images are not fulfilling what they are supposed to prevent, some online applications decided to use something else instead.